# Where can I go for live chat support?

Tags: community, support

I got Ubuntu installed few years ago and never got any training on how to use this system so I am looking for live chat for questions I may have as they come up.

Is this available?

Comment: You may want to study the [Ubuntu Manual](http://ubuntu-manual.org/). As regards possible need to upgrade: Which Ubuntu version do you currently have?

Comment: At this moment, if you're not running 12.04, 14.04, or 15.10 you will want to upgrade. Those are the supported releases. 12.04 will be supported through 2017, 14.04 through 2019, and 15.10 through May 2016.

Answer (score 13):

### TL;DR

Join #ubuntu on Libera.chat or join us in [the Ask Ubuntu chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

---

Ubuntu (and Linux in general) uses IRC for support and collaboration quite extensively. If you're not familiar with IRC [take a look at this beginners guide.](https://fedoramagazine.org/beginners-guide-irc/) The #ubuntu channel is where ubuntu support happens, and where you will want to ask your questions.

You'll need an IRC client. I recommend [hexchat](https://hexchat.github.io/) which you can install with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install hexchat
```

When you open it, hexchat will ask you to input several usernames (in case your first choice is already taken):

[image]

Input a few usernames (or use the populated ones), select "Libera.chat" from the networks list and click "connect".

[image]

You're in! Now join the #ubuntu channel by typing:

```
/join #ubuntu
```

and pressing enter. Ask your question! Be detailed and show your research. Don't be a [help vampire.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)